# Negation of a quantified statement

Tags: logic, quantifiers, predicate-logic

I would like to negate the following:

$\exists x, \forall y, \forall z  ((F(x,y) \land G(x,z)) \rightarrow H(y,z))$

Would the following proposed solution be correct?

(1) First simplify what is in the brackets - 
$((F(x,y) \land G(x,z)) \rightarrow H(y,z))$

$(\lnot(F(x,y) \land G(x,z)) \lor  H(y,z))$

(2) $\forall x, \exists y, \exists z \lnot ( \lnot(F(x,y) \land G(x,z)) \lor  H(y,z)) $

$\equiv \forall x, \exists y, \exists z((F(x,y) \land G(x,z)) \land \lnot  H(y,z))$

Comment: Yes, though you’ve done a little more work than necessary. If you remember that $\lnot(\varphi\to\psi)$ is $\varphi\land\lnot\psi$, you can go directly to $$\forall x\exists y\exists z\Big(F(x,y)\land G(x,z)\land\lnot H(y,z)\Big)\;.$$

Comment: cheers @BrianM.Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The negation of $P \Rightarrow Q$ is $$\neg(P \Rightarrow Q) \equiv (P \wedge \neg Q)$$
and the negation of "for all" is
$$\neg (\forall x)(P(x)) \equiv (\exists x)(\neg P(x)).$$
Similarly,
$$\neg (\exists x)(P(x)) \equiv (\forall x)(\neg P(x))$$
so your answer is correct.